# 2 Shadow DOMs in one HTML page

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I want to create/inject/set two Shadow DOMs in one Angular app with both CSS and js per each.

For the CSS - I know how to isolate it.

For the js - I have a collision with both variables and functions names.

Any idea?

**index.html:**

[image: index.html]

**index2.html**

[image: index2.html]

1. I make HTTP req in order to get the HTML files (with CSS and js).
2. create a shadow dow per each
3. append the file to the shadow dom
4. and I'm getting this error

**Error:**

[image: error]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you show us the code you have done? It will be easier to answer.

Comment: You could encasulate the declaration of x in a try/catch.

Comment: Or use a modern approach with `require` and a build tool...

Comment: @Supersharp think about it like this - I will get these files (HTML with CSS and js) from another team. I can't force them. it could be. (for variable and functions)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hi, do you have an example?

Comment: you cannot define a global variable 2 times. The 2 scripts are not compatible. What do you really want?

Comment: @Supersharp A situation in which 2 teams gave me their components like so (HTML with a link to CSS and script tag)
how can I avoid a collision with a global variable?
I want 2 shadow dom completely isolated

Comment: you should put the 2 components into 2 different iframe

Answer (score 0):

ShadowDOM creates a sandbox for both DOM and CSS but it does not create a sandbox for code.

JS Code, whether loaded using `<script src="filename"></script>` or `<script>code</script>` is placed into a single namespace.

If you need to prevent code from stepping on other code then try the following:

- Use ES6 modules if you can run on only newer browsers. `<script src="filename" type="module"></script>` https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/
- Place the code in an IIFE:

```
(function () {
  // your code
})()
```

This loads the function and creates a new scope placing all of your code in that scope.

- Use classes https://devdocs.io/javascript/classes

This allows you to create a chunk of code encapsulated in the class which can be reused.